# Google Drive API - Change "Shared" setting

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm building an API that allows users to have access to the list of files hosted on google drive, and I'm reading documentation to see if there are enough resources to make it possible.

My idea is to **allow** user **to update the visibility** of a single file. In the documentation this option is marked under the property "**shared**" with a boolean value.

In the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) of "**File > Update**" method I didn't find a parameter that could let me do this.

In the generic Google Drive interface this option is available through the "Share" option which prompts you a window where you set the visibility to "*Private*" /  "*Public on web*" / "*Whoever has the link*".

Am I able to do this with the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, posting the solution below:

To set a file "sharable" you must set permissions in [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) api call in this way:

```
var resource = {
  'value': 'default',
  'type': 'anyone',
  'role': 'reader'
};
var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
  'fileId': fileId,
  'resource': resource
}).execute(function() { 
  alert("file set to public")
});
```

to set the file back to private there is update and [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/delete) method. In case of "delete", this is the way to perform it:

```
  var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.delete({
    'fileId': fileId,
    'permissionId': 'anyone'
  }).execute(function() { 
    alert("public permissions revoked")
  });
```